# Can map model to viewModel, but viewModel to model won't work

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I use Automapper to map my domain model to my viewModel and this works great. Atm I'm just prototyping and changing the Model a lot, so at this point my viewModel is almost an exact copy of my Model and my viewModel references classes from the domain for its complex types (so I only have to keep the root class of my viewModel in sync with my domain model).

Although mapping from the domain model to the viewModel works great, mapping the viewModel back to the domain model doesn't work very well. The values directly in the viewModel do map, but the lists of a complex type don't. How do i fix this?

This is a simple representation of my models:

```
public class model
{
    public int someValue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ComplexType> aList { get; set; }
}
public class viewModel
{
    public int someValue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ComplexType> aList { get; set; }
}
public class ComplexType
{
    public int someOtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

In this case they both model and viewModel reference the same file for *ComplexType* so these can't differ.

Comment: Did you solve your issue Paul?

Comment: Not yet. Had a quick try a your solution last weekend, but it doesn't work yet. I hope to have some more time for this tomorrow.

Comment: if `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` doesn't kick up a fuss but you're still receiving an error it may be an issue I can't help with. But copying the code from my answer worked with the basic Models you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use ReverseMap when mapping from ViewModel to Domain Model?

```cs
public class CustomProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        // Mapper.CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>();
        // Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel, Model>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine and maps everything with no issue.

```cs
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(conf => conf.AddProfile(new CustomProfile()));
}

[TestMethod]
public void AssertConfiguration()
{
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var model = new Model()
        {
            ComplexTypes = new Collection<ComplexType>() { new ComplexType() { SomeOtherValue = 1 }, new ComplexType() { SomeOtherValue = 4 } },
            SomeValue = 3
        };

    var viewModel = Mapper.Map<ViewModel>(model);

    Assert.AreEqual(model.SomeValue, viewModel.SomeValue);
    Assert.AreEqual(model.ComplexTypes.Count, viewModel.ComplexTypes.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(model.ComplexTypes.ElementAt(0), viewModel.ComplexTypes.ElementAt(0));
    Assert.AreEqual(model.ComplexTypes.ElementAt(1), viewModel.ComplexTypes.ElementAt(1));

    model = Mapper.Map<Model>(viewModel);

    Assert.AreEqual(viewModel.SomeValue, model.SomeValue);
    Assert.AreEqual(viewModel.ComplexTypes.Count, model.ComplexTypes.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(viewModel.ComplexTypes.ElementAt(0), model.ComplexTypes.ElementAt(0));
    Assert.AreEqual(viewModel.ComplexTypes.ElementAt(1), model.ComplexTypes.ElementAt(1));
}
```

Comment: `.ReverseMap();` in combination with `.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` finaly helped me solve this. The problem was an error in my models. Thx!

Comment: That's great! `.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` is super handy.